# Collecting data for machine translation

Tags: python, corpus, machine-translation

I am interested in trying to make a machine translation for language accents and is curious for methods avaialable to collect data or how to make your own corpus with unlimited resource. Any good reference i could refer to or ideas?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried?

Comment: for this project i haven't really started. i only tried compiling according to examples online and most of them used the corpus that was available online.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of open corpora you may wish to look at, many of which are collated here on the [The Open Parallel Corpus (OPUS)](http://opus.nlpl.eu/), to seed some data for your exercise.

In terms of building and collecting your own, you could consider [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/), or doing generation with something like [Snorkel](https://github.com/snorkel-team/snorkel).

Answer (score -2):

What kind of realization you need? if it just shell programm, it is easy? if you want GUI(Tkinter) or WEB (Djano) app?